# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2352 into shape (1,28,28)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, mnist

I want to use my drawing for my neural network. I trained it on MNIST. I can’t prepare from any way. I drew a figure in a 28x28 picture resolution. I try to run it through the neural network, but it doesn't work. I don't understand how to fix this problem.

CODE

```
    #norm_image = np.asarray(pixels, dtype=np.float32) / 255
img_size=28
img = cv2.resize(img, (img_size,img_size))
x=img
x=np.asarray(img)
x = img.astype('float32')
x /= 255.0
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
images = np.vstack([x])
print(images.shape)
images = np.reshape(images,(1, 28, 28))

#print(pixels)
#print(x.shape)
#res=model.predict(x)
#print (res)
#print(f"Распознанная цифра: {np.argmax(res)}")
#x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
#plt.imshow(img, cmap=plt.cm.binary)
#plt.show()
```

Errore

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-167-3fe66f8f6d63> in <module>()
     13 images = np.vstack([x])
     14 print(images.shape)
---> 15 images = np.reshape(images,(1, 28, 28))
     16 
     17 #print(pixels)

<__array_function__ internals> in reshape(*args, **kwargs)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     56 
     57     try:
---> 58         return bound(*args, **kwds)
     59     except TypeError:
     60         # A TypeError occurs if the object does have such a method in its

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2352 into shape (1,28,28)
```

Comment: img = cv2.imread("t7.png")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you read your image in color mode instead of grayscale (`BGR` in OpenCV), but the order of channel is not of essence here (ofc `2352 // 3 = 784`).

As you have an image read of `28x28x3` = `2352`, you want to reshape it into `28x28x1` = `784`, which of course does not work as it the error suggests.

The problem lies in the way you read the image: `img = cv2.imread("t7.png")`. Instead use `img = cv2.imread("t7.png",0)`, the parameter `0` being the default flag for grayscale image.

Comment: I fix this problem . I use image= np.mean(a,2,dtype=float) . this fix my problem)

Comment: That is a trick, you use the mean on axis=2 which is doing across all the 3 channels, so practically what you do is instead of saying 28 you say 28 = (28 + 28 + 28) / 3

Comment: If you read the image grayscale you will not need to do that mean on the axis=2.